# iOS5 CoreData Entity showing wrong NSNumber value, works on iOS4

Tags: ios, core-data, ios5, nsnumber

I have a CoreData entity with an NSNumber property (an Integer 16 in the model). I have the following code:

```
NSLog(@"raw changeAmount=%d", changeAmount);

NSNumber *changeNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:changeAmount];

NSLog(@"number changeAmount=%d = %@", [changeNumber intValue], changeNumber);

record.changeAmount = changeNumber;

NSLog(@"new changeAmount=%d", [record.changeAmount intValue]);
```

`changeAmount` is an int with the value 123000 when I run my test. When I test on iOS 4, everything works properly and prints out 123000. However, if I run this same code on iOS 5, the value is something like -8072 or -25,536. Like so:

```
raw changeAmount=123000
number changeAmount=123000 = 123000
new changeAmount=-8072
```

What the heck happened between iOS4 and iOS5 that is causing this? Have I been setting my NSNumber properties incorrectly this entire time?

It doesn't appear to be an integer size issue, because I changed the model to use integer 32 (which it should have been all along) and it's still happening. So we aren't getting integer overflow or anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just run this code in CodeRunner

```
size_t shortSize = sizeof(short);
size_t intSize   = sizeof(int);

short short123000 = 123000;
int   int123000   = 123000;

NSString *format = @"\nshortSize       => %d\n"
                   @"int Size          => %d\n"
                   @"short with 123000 => %d\n"
                   @"int with 123000   => %d";

NSLog(format, shortSize, intSize, short123000, int123000);
```

which results in:

```
shortSize         => 2  
int Size          => 4  
short with 123000 => -8072  
int with 123000   => 123000
```

**NB** The size is in bytes and there are 8 bits in a byte thus 2*8 = 16bit and 4*8 = 32bit.

I had similar issues with some of the apps I work on. It would appear that CoreData has become a bit stricter about enforcing its types. I was caught out by it to but I should have been more vigilant about what I was doing, if Apple had changed their API so that it did not behave as it is supposed to people would complain but when the API is changed to do what it advertised in the first place it's just unfortunate and likely to catch people out.

As you can see this is a simple integer overflow so if you know the range your working in you can easily fix this up.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the response! I edited my post while you were typing because I thought the same thing. I updated my model to be int32s but it's still happening. I'm going to assume that something is wrong with updating the model because the -8072 can't be a coincidence. Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to guess that although you updated your model the value has already been persisted in your database as -8072 therefore when you do a migration how does the migration know that -8072 is not what you wanted? It couldn't just assume that the value has overflowed.

Comment: Ah found it! I apparently was updating the wrong model. I created a new version before the change, set the new version as the current version and I THOUGHT I was editing the new version, but alas, no. I changed the old model back to int16 and the new model to int32 and it's working as intended now.